# Is there a service like an SMTP proxy that can extract and store attachments and replace them with links?

Tags: smtp, email-attachments

Assume I am supporting an existing software-as-a-service application which can email users via SMTP. The email may sometimes contain attachments. The attachments are generally reports in Excel format.

Sometimes attachments are larger than the receiving mail server will allow, and the mail bounces.

I am envisioning a service that would act as an SMTP proxy and sit in between my application and my SMTP mail service. This service would extract attachments and store them somewhere, perhaps Amazon S3, and replace the attachment in the email with a unique link to download the attachment.

Is anyone aware of such a service?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [MIMEDefang](http://www.mimedefang.org/) milter as an addon to sendmail or postfix.

http://www.roaringpenguin.com/products/mimedefang

> MIMEDefang can inspect and modify e-mail messages as they pass through your mail relay. MIMEDefang is written in Perl, and its filter actions are expressed in Perl, so it's highly flexible. Here are some things that you can do very easily with MIMEDefang:
>   [...]
>   * Replace large attachments with links to a centrally-stored copy to ease the burden on POP3 users with slow modem links.

http://www.mimedefang.org/

> MIMEDefang is free software: It's released under the terms of the GNU General Public License. It runs under Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris and most other UNIX or UNIX-like systems.

Comment: Interesting option, thanks. It's been a long time since I've written Perl :)